# Flutter Firebase whereContains two values

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my code.  I have two input parameters authUser and chatUser.  I have a record called Chats, with a List field called users.  I want to query and get the document where the List field users contains BOTH authUser and chatUser.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

Future<ChatsRecord> getChatDocFromChatUserAuthUser(
  DocumentReference? chatUserRef,
  DocumentReference? authUserRef,
) async {
  // Add your function code here!

  ChatsRecord chatDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('chats')
      .where("users", arrayContains: chatUserRef)
      .where("users", arrayContains: authUser)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot));

  return chatDoc;
}
```

Here is the error I get from trying the solution below:

```
lib/custom_code/actions/get_chat_doc.dart:23:34:
Error: A value of type 'List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>>' can't be returned from an async function with return type 'Future<List<ChatsRecord>>'.
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' is from 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart' ('/root/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-4.2.0/lib/cloud_firestore.dart').
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'ChatsRecord' is from 'package:counter_party/backend/schema/chats_record.dart' ('lib/backend/schema/chats_record.dart').
  return (await snapshots.first).toList();
                                 ^
Error: Compilation failed.
```

Comment: So basically you need to need to `arrayContains` calls? Is that correct?

Comment: yes, I know that what I wrote is not permitted, but I am describing the desired behavior.  I would like to check whether BOTH chatUserRef AND authUser are in the users field which is a list.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using conditions from `QuerySnapshots` by :

```
CollectionReference chatDoc = Firestore.instance.collection('chats');
final snapshots = chatDoc.snapshots().map((snapshot) => snapshot.documents.where((doc) => doc["users"] == chatUserRef || doc["users"] == authUser));

return (await snapshots.first).toList();
```

Comment: Thank you!~. I will try that!  Do I need to add packages to support this other than the firestore from pub.dev?

Comment: None all of this is already available in flutter

Comment: do upvote and mark as answer if you're satisfied

Comment: done....I haven't tried it yet, though.

Comment: yeah yeah mark it if it works that is... and tell me if it doesn't

Comment: Oh I need it to be AND.  chatUserRef AND authUser must both be in the field "users"...maybe I am reading this wrong but it looks like it is an OR operator.

Comment: I expect there to be only one chatDoc where chatDoc.users.contains(authUser AND chatUser) (if AND were supported in contains)

Comment: I get an error saying there is no getting called documents: https://a.cl.ly/p9uLNOq2

Comment: Yeah my bad it should be snapshot.docs

Comment: ah okay I think I tried it but my IDE didn't autopopulate it.  Let me check again.

Comment: I get an error adding above.